# How can I make a named list or vector from environment objects, using the object names?

Tags: r

I am trying to take objects in my environment, and put them into a list or vector that is named with the names of the object. Here is an illustration:

```r
a = 1
b = 2

desired <- c(a, b)
names(desired) <- c("a", "b")
desired
#> a b 
#> 1 2
```

My attempts have been variations of the following. I can see why this doesn't work (even if my terminology might not quite be right): it's pausing the evaluation after figuring out that `...` is `1, 2`. However, I want some way to get it to give `a, b` so that I can put the names on properly. I am open to any solutions, in base R, `rlang` or others.

```r
name_list <- function(...){
  names <- enquote(list(...))
  values <- list(...)
  return(names)
}
print(name_list(a, b))
#> quote(list(1, 2))
```

Created on 2018-07-10 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).

Comment: The `tibble::lst` function does this in a "tidyverse way": `tibble::lst(a, b)`. If you want to see how it does it, just type the name of the function without the parenthesis to see the source code: `tibble::lst`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `match.call` to retrieve the names of the arguments being passed in

```
name_list <- function(...){
  vnames <- as.character(match.call())[-1]
  return(setNames(list(...), vnames))
}
a = 1; b=c(1,2)
name_list(a, b)
```

Comment: ah great, that's awesome! will keep that one around for sure